# JRTPLIB - MJPEG - JPEG

Tags: rtp

i am using the JRTPLIB http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/jori/jrtplib/documentation/index.html
to implement a MJPEG stream via RTP. But I don't understand how to stream the MJPEG. The lib has a method called `RTPSession::SendPacket(const void *data, size_t len)`. I don't get it, what needs to be done with a JPEG to get it inside the RTP Package? Where is the difference between a MJPEG and a JPEG in this context.

```
//DEFAULT RTP PACKAGE Parameters//
sess.SetDefaultMark(MARK);
sess.SetDefaultPayloadType(PAYLOADTYPE);      //Setting 26 for RTP MJPEG Payload             
sess.SetDefaultTimestampIncrement(TIMESTAMPINC);

for (i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++)
{
    printf("\nSending packet %d/%d\n",i,num);

    // send the packet
    status = sess.SendPacket((void *)"1234567890",10);             
    checkerror(status);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MJPEG is a ad-junction of JPEG files, you can find MJPEG in Http or Rtp and there is no difference from JPEG besides that the headers are stripped in the RTP Variation and in the Http variation there is a Content-Boundary which separates all JPEGs

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, in the meantime I've already written my own RTP/RTPS Streamer for MJPEG. It works with the VLC player but the interesting part is that it only works if I don't remove the initial JPEG header from the image but simply but a RTP header in front of it.

Comment: Correct that is called de-packetization...

See my library @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ which also has an implementation of this